# Get value of control refnum in one step in SubVI

Tags: labview

I'm trying to de-spaghetti a big UI by creating SubVIs that handle only the controls that are relevant, via control refnums.

Now, when extracting the code from the main VI and re-wiring into the subVIs, things get clutter-y.

To read/write these refnums, I have to do a two-step process. First add a terminal to get the control refnum value and then another to get the value of the control.

[image: get value from refnum]

Wiring the refnums everywhere is not really an option as that will create more  spaghetti if there are more than two of them. (usually 4-10)

Is there a better way?

**UPDATE**

Guys, this is a low-level question about the picture above, not really a queston about large scale architecture / design patterns. I'm using QMH, classes,  et.al. where appropriate.

I just feel there should be a way to get the typed value from a typed control ref in one step. It feels kind of common.

Comment: Is the code you're trying to clean up all strictly UI code, or is it a big mess of UI and application logic? If the former, srm's suggestion of bundling the references into clusters sounds good; if the latter, you should probably go for a more fundamental rework of the thing as Joe Friedrichsen proposes.

Comment: A bit of both. I mostly just wanted a do what I do in the picture in one step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the caller VI, where the controls/indicators actually live, create all your references, then bundle them into clusters of relevant pieces. Pass the clusters into your subVIs, giving a given subVI only the cluster it needs. This both keeps your conpane cleaned up and and makes it clear the interface that each subVI is talking to. Instead of a cluster, you may want to create a LV class to further encapsulate and define the sub-UI operations, but that's generally only on larger projects where some components of the UI will be reused in other UIs.

Comment: Thanks. This helps with reducing ref-spaghetti in the front manel

Comment: Altough, I still have to do two nodes to get value in the subvi, instead of one step as the previous code was. Sad.

Comment: This becomes three steps: local variable of cluster, unbundle by name, get value from ref. :(   Using a cluster is useful when I have to share groups of controls, but otherwise it seems to create even more wiring in the subvi:s.

Comment: Static refs to controls are only possible in the actual VI where those controls are in scope, so there will always be at least 2 nodes for access. The extra Bundle/Unbundle nodes pay off when you start having multiple layers of subVIs as you further refine your code. If you create a small inlined accessor VI (unbundle ref, read or write Value) then your caller code never sees the extra nodes.

Comment: Can I write such an inline accessor for any type? That's would help a bit.

Comment: No. LabVIEW doesn't have generics or templates. The only polymorphism like that is in the primitives.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a low-touch way to de-spaghetti a UI with lots of controls and indicators.

My suggestion is to rework the top-level VI into a [queued message handler](https://decibel.ni.com/content/blogs/labview-news-english/2013/04/19/complex-application-use-the-queued-message-handler), which would allow you to decouple the user interaction from the application's response. In other words, rather than moving *both* the controls and the code that handles their changes to subVIs (as you're currently doing), this would keep the controls where they are (so you don't need to use ref nums and property nodes) and only move the code to subVIs.

This design pattern is built-in to recent versions of LabVIEW: navigate to **File » Create Project** to make LabVIEW generate a project you can evaluate. For more information about understanding how to extend and customize it, see this NI slide deck: [Decisions Behind the Design of the
Queued Message Handler Template](ftp://ftp.ni.com/pub/events/labview_dev_ed/2014/decisions_behind_the_design_of_the_queued_message_handler_template.pdf).

[image: QMH: producer-consumer for events]

Comment: Agreed: this may be more work up front than the control reference approach but will be more extensible and maintainable in the long run. Using control references is really OK only if the code being refactored is strictly all UI code and is already well separated from the application logic.

Comment: It turns into message passing hell quite quickly, if each UI event updates 5-6 controls. Using refnums keeps the logic & controls quite tightly coupled, which is how the app's part actually work. I use QMH when there is less coupling between UI and logic/processing,

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not the best practice to read/write value using refnum in perspective of performance. It requires a thread swap to the UI thread each time (which is a heavy process), whereas the FP Terminal is privileged to be able to update the panel without switching execution threads and without mutex friction.

> **Using references to access value**
>   Requires to update the front panel item every single time they are called.
>   They are a pass by reference function as opposed to a pass by value function.  This means they are essentially pointers to specific memory locations.  The pointers must be de-referenced, and then the value in memory updated.  The process of de-referencing the variables causes them to be slower than Controls/Indicators, or Local Variables.
>   Property Nodes cause the front panel of a SubVI to remain in memory, which increases memory use.  If the front panel of a SubVI is not displayed, remove property nodes to decrease memory use.

If after this you want to use this method you can use VI scripting to speed up the process: http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209110

Comment: Hi! While your answer is insightful, this doesn't answer my question about simplyfing the de-ref process nor does it provide an alternative design that sidesteps the issue. Your answer is better suited as a comment. FWIW, performance is not a problem here, the issue is rather code complexity.

Comment: The second part is the answer: If after this you want to use this method you can use VI scripting to speed up the process: http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209110